# Python: testing inter-dependence between strings

Tags: python, string, logic

I have a piece of code which compares two strings.

If they are both empty (i.e. `""`), the code should return `True`

If they are both 'populated', the code should return `True`

otherwise (i.e. one is empty), the code should return `False`

Currently I have:

```
def compare(first, second):

        if first:
            return bool(second)
        elif second:
            return bool(first) 
        else:
            return True
```

I'm sure there is a more succinct way to do this with fewer clauses (or ideally no clauses)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the inverse of "exclusive `or`":

```
>>> def compare(first, second):
    return not bool(first) ^ bool(second)

>>> compare("", "")
True
>>> compare("foo", "")
False
>>> compare("", "bar")
False
>>> compare("foo", "bar")
True
```

Comment: this looks good thanks. I hadn't thought of the caret operator. I'll do a couple of performance tests but I imagine it should be both quicker than my method and deterministic, which is a big plus

Answer (score -1):

```
return len(first) == len(second) == 0 or len(first) > 0 and len(second) > 0
```

Or

```
return a==b=='' or a!='' and b!=''
```

You shouldn't count on boolean operators on strings

Comment: The [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) disagrees with you: *"For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false."*

Comment: Was about to answer with `len` too: `return (len(first+second)==0) or (len(first)*len(second)>0)`

Comment: Don't really see how this is more succinct. In fact, multiple calls to other functions surely less succinct?